# Using Azure cloud directly to implement paho-mqtt in C, "Failed to connect"?

Tags: linux, azure, ssl, mqtt, paho

I'm trying to send and receive messages using azure cloud but directly on paho-mqtt and not on azure-mqtt SDK in a Raspberry-pi 3. I have followed all the instructions mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly). I have generated the SSL certs and have placed in the /etc/certs file path also. I have made necessary changes in the code like ClientID,Address,etc. but when I try to run the code, I get an error.

> error :  Failed to connect, return code -1

Here is the code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "MQTTClient.h"

#define ADDRESS     "xxxxxxxx.azure-devices.net:8883"
#define CLIENTID    "Device-Id"
#define TOPIC       "devices/Device-Id/messages/events/"
#define PAYLOAD     "Hello World!"
#define QOS         0
#define TIMEOUT     10000L

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MQTTClient client;
    MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
    MQTTClient_message pubmsg = MQTTClient_message_initializer;
    MQTTClient_deliveryToken token;
    int rc;

    MQTTClient_create(&client, ADDRESS, CLIENTID,
        MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL);
    conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
    conn_opts.cleansession = 1;
    conn_opts.username = "xxxxxx.azure-devices.net/Device-ID/api-version=2017-11-25";
    conn_opts.password = "SharedAccessSignature sr=xxxxx.azure-devices.net&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5&skn=Device-ID";
    conn_opts.ssl->truststore = "/etc/certs/ca.crt";

    if ((rc = MQTTClient_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    pubmsg.payload = PAYLOAD;
    pubmsg.payloadlen = strlen(PAYLOAD);
    pubmsg.qos = QOS;
    pubmsg.retained = 0;
    MQTTClient_publishMessage(client, TOPIC, &pubmsg, &token);
    printf("Waiting for up to %d seconds for publication of %s\n"
            "on topic %s for client with ClientID: %s\n",
            (int)(TIMEOUT/1000), PAYLOAD, TOPIC, CLIENTID);
    rc = MQTTClient_waitForCompletion(client, token, TIMEOUT);
    printf("Message with delivery token %d delivered\n", token);
    MQTTClient_disconnect(client, 10000);
    MQTTClient_destroy(&client);
    return rc;
}
```

I'm not sure what is wrong here. Help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you've placed your certs in `/etc/certs` why are you pointing at `/etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt`?

Comment: oops! sorry, I was checking different directories and forgot to change the path before I posted the question here, the point is I have checked all the directories I have my certs in and it still doesn't work. (made the changes in the code).